# Gravatars shown incorrectly on "top network askers" sidebar

Tags: bug, gravatar, top-users

The "Top Network Askers" sidebar shows a bunch of similar gravatars for users, where their gravatars are actually something different. In this case they all seem to link to

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=18&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;s=30"/>
```

Clicking through to the users shows different gravatars (since you can't click on the image, here are a few):

- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/27070/florian
- https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/94549/sally-nguyen
- https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/35433/rachel-bailey

[image]